# .net API for managing pst files

Tags: c#

I have an old PC on which i have a large pst file , and i have the idea to write a small C# program to spilt it into smaller files so that i can better manage them if needed ( i know that sounds weird and that there are also available tools in google but i thought it will be fun to play with it ).The problem is that i can't find good article or API info which functions are best suited ( if there are any at all ) for managing those files , Ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a PST file? What program do you use them in? What type of information do they store?

Comment: You are supposed to answer questions, Cody.  You asking what is a PST file is a totally useless response.  You have Google to answer that.  You deserve not to be taken seriously when you post things like this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Redemption API](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). This API does not require Outlook to be installed (only stand-alone MAPI) and does not require outlook to run.

Comment: Are you sure it does not require outlook installed to run? from the site "For the properties and methods not blocked by the Security Patch, all calls are transparently forwarded to the Outlook object that you assign to the Item property"

Comment: @David Waters: For the RDO* objects, outlook is not necessary (home page: `The RDO family of objects can also be used with the Exchange Server or standalone versions of Extended MAPI (Exchange 5.5 through 2010)`). Howver, most people use this API in outlook add-ins; especially because of the sercurity patch.

Answer (score 2):

First just a clarification by PST file you mean you outlook information?
Running on that I know of no API to manipulate it but you can get the documentation for it at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx) this is a large and complex specification for a binary format. Always play with a copy of it not the real thing.

One approach that might be better is using the ActiveX/COM interface provided by outlook to interact with this file abstractly, so instead of dealing with the [physical layout](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC380495.jpg) of the file work with contacts, folder and email messages.

It may be worth your while finding out how open source mail clients (Like thunderbird) import from outlook. You may be able to pull there code out into an API, as long as you follow the licence conditions.

Not the easier answer, but it is the one I have.

Comment: @Aetius1 : You most welcome, if my answer or Sam B's answer have been sufficient in solving your issue please mark the best one as accepted. This helps motivate people to be helpful on this site.